# python: extracting text from any website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

so far i have done my work but it successfully getting text from these two websites :

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm
- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/

But I don't know where I am doing wrong and it is not getting text from other websites and it's is giving me error when i place other links such as:

- http://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/~akin/cmpe223/chap2.htm
- http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/477-trees.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\data extraction.py", line 20, in 
>       text = soup.select('.C_doc')[0].get_text()
>   IndexError: list index out of range

My code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/477-trees.html" #unsuccessfull 
#url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm"   #doing successfully
#url = "http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/" #doing successfully
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style","a","<div id=\"bottom\" >"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
#text = soup.select('.C_doc')[0].get_text()
#text = soup.select('.content')[0].get_text()

if soup.select('.content'):
    text = soup.select('.content')[0].get_text()
else:
    text = soup.select('.C_doc')[0].get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print text
fo = open('foo.txt', 'w')
fo.seek(0, 2)
line = fo.writelines( text )
fo.close()
#writing done :)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Text = soup.findAll(text=True)
```

**UPDATE**

This is a basic text stripper you can start from.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/477-trees.html" 
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for script in soup(["script", "style","a","<div id=\"bottom\" >"]):
    script.extract()    

text = soup.findAll(text=True)
for p in text:
    print p
```

Comment: shall i place inside if-else?? or away?

Comment: outside. This will get all results

Comment: can u post the answer?? bcz i am not getting any data in text

Comment: i am getting this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\nd.py", line 12, in <module>
    print p
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1344, in write
    s = unicode.__getslice__(s, None, None)
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: it works fine on Python 2.7.8  in Linux and on other version. Do not know about windows and pyshell but code is quite easy . Your error seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295950/bs4-soup-title-string-doesnt-work-on-idle-but-terminal try print (unicode(p))

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming all websites that you scrap has class name `content` OR `C_doc`.
What if the website you scrap does not have such class name `C_doc`?

Here is the fix:

```
text = ''
    if soup.select('.content'):
        text = soup.select('.content')[0].get_text()
    elif soup.select('.C_doc'):
        text = soup.select('.C_doc')[0].get_text()

if text:
    #put rest of the code.
else:
    print 'text does not exists.'
```

Comment: yea by doing so i am not getting anything in the text and again giving me the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\data extraction.py", line 21, in <module>
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
NameError: name 'text' is not defined     so how should i encounter this?

Comment: That means whatever site you're giving does not have .content OR .C_doc

Comment: is that what you have said: text = ''
if soup.select('.content'):
    text = soup.select('.content')[0].get_text()
elif soup.select('.C_doc'):
    text = soup.select('.C_doc')[0].get_text()

if text:
    #put rest of the code.
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
else:
    print 'text does not exists.'

Comment: yes. read the code and it will be obvious. if text does not exists, dont do anything, but if it does, do your logic.

Comment: i am getting this then : "WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER."

Comment: i am failed in getting can i get text dynamically from any website??